# Is there a way to form connections between nodes based upon if they have shared attributes?

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, nodes, networkx

My goal is to write a program that starts with an unconnected network of nodes, each node with possibly identical or different attributes. Then if the nodes have shared attributes, an edge will form. So far I have looked through the networks package and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to achieve this. If anybody has any ideas of how to do it, I would really appreciate the help!

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
know_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(1,5):
    G.add_node(i, knowledge = know_list[i-1])

#nx.draw(G)
#plt.show()
knowledge=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'knowledge')
print(knowledge)

G.add_node(5, awareness = random.choices(know_list, k=2))
awareness = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'awareness')
print(awareness)`
```

#The goal after returning a dictionary of the awareness of node 5 is to compare what is in the awareness dictionary to the dictionary of knowledge (note that get_node_attributes returns a dictionary with nodes as keys and elements from know_list as items). If an element in the awareness dictionary is the same as a node's knowledge attribute, then add an edge between the two. For example, suppose that random choice gives awareness = [a,b]. In this case, node 5 will form connections to nodes 1 and 2, because node one has a knowledge of [a] and node 2 has knowledge [b]. But, node 5 will not form a connection with nodes 3 or 4, because those are not elements contained in the awareness dictionary. I hope this clears up some things, let me know if it is still confusing.

Comment: Can you define similar? Could you also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I edited the original post to contain what I have so far of code (granted it is not very much). I also tried to describe what I am trying to achieve in better detail with an example. I hope this helps clear up the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the graph you've shared:

```
know_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(1,5):
    G.add_node(i, knowledge = know_list[i-1])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='lightgreen')
```

[image]

You could invert the mapping returned by the `nx.get_node_attributes` of the `knowledge` attribute:

```
knowledge={j:i for i,j in nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'knowledge').items()}
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

G.add_node(5, awareness = random.choices(know_list, k=2))
awareness = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'awareness')
# {5: ['b', 'a']}
```

Then by iterating over `awareness`, you can easily add new edges by looking up in `knowledge` the nodes in the inner lists using [`add_edge`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html):

```
for k,v in awareness.items():
    for node in v:
        G.add_edge(k,knowledge[node])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='lightgreen')
```

[image]